# Use Devise's current_user in all associated controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a question about good practice.  I am about to implement (just started) Pundit for my authorisation.  However, in my controllers, say Projects and Stages I am associating all of my calls using current_user. e.g.

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /projects
  # GET /projects.json
  def index
    @projects = current_user.Projects.all
    authorize @projects    
  end

  # GET /projects/1
  # GET /projects/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project
      @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])
      authorize @project
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_params
      params[:title, :description]
    end
end
```

I will have many more associations that are associated to a user (or many users).  Is the above a good method to ensure that users can only view projects that they are allowed to? And is an authorisation 'gem' therefore not required?

Thanks in advance
Rudy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: yes, what you're doing with Devise's `current_user` is fine. As for an authorisation gem, you may or may not still need one.

The longer answer:

It's first worth briefly clarifying the difference between authentication and authorisation.

**authentication** is about saying "is this user who they say they are?". If I log in with the username 'bob', and also am able to correctly enter bob's password, then your app (via the help of devise) is able to say *"OK, yep, I believe this user is who they say they are - I believe that it is in fact Bob on the end of the keyboard"*. That is to say, Bob is **authenticated**.

**authorisation** is about saying "is this user allowed to do what they are trying to do". For example, Bob may be able to create new projects, but he might not be allowed to delete projects. That is to say, Bob is *authorised* to create projects, and is not *authorised* to delete them.

OK. Now, **authentication** allows you, in and of itself, to perform some level of **authorisation**, because you can say *"logged in users can view projects, but logged out users can't"*. Or you may want to say, as you are, *"logged in users can view their own projects (but no one elses), but logged out users can't view any projects"*.

This last scenario is referred to as "scoping" by the logged in user, and the way you're doing it (using Devise's `current_user`) is just fine.

The last thing is the question of wether or not you need an **authentication** gem, in addition to the **authorisation** provided by Devise. If all you need to do is distinguish between *logged in* users and *non-logged in* users, then Devise should be all you need, and there's no need for an authentication gem.

If, on the other hand, you need more fine-grained authentication (for example, logged in users who are also admins can delete their own projects, but logged in users who are not admins can only view their own projects, and cannot delete them), then you'll likely want an authorisation gem, in addition to Devise.

Comment: Perfect thank you for your answer and peace of mind with my approach.  I will still need authorisation as I will end up adding roles etc. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's ok if you don't need any advanced control features (like read-only).

Comment: Thanks for your assistance,the other answer was more in depth. Ta